# Adding a column from another table into existing SQL/query statement

Tags: java, sql, teradata

Currently, I have a query that I  run in my java code that displays just a simple grid output of columns with the corresponding data for those specific fields. I am reading 2 tables that all have the same column names. I need to add just 1 column to that grid, but the field name resides on a different table. How would I add this to my existing query?

This is my current query that I execute in the Java:

```
    SELECT  TRNSP_EQP_EIN, TRNSP_EQP_ID, PRE_EQP_ID, EQP_GRP, AAR_CT_C,
AAR_MCHDSG_C,BLD_D, REBLD_D
FROM  EQ.TE_TRNSP_EQPACTV  A
WHERE TRNSP_EQP_ID = ‘BNSF0000000123’
UNION
SELECT TRNSP_EQP_EIN, TRNSP_EQP_ID, PRE_EQP_ID, EQP_GRP, AAR_CT_C,
AAR_MCHDSG_C,BLD_D, REBLD_D
FROM  EQ.TE_TRNSP_EQPHIST  A
WHERE A.TRNSP_EQP_ID = ‘ABC0123’

ORDER BY TRNSP_EQP_EFF_TS
WITH UR
```

Below is the information that I am trying to add to the grid to the existing SQL.

Table: EQ.TE_LOCO_EQP

Field: DEL_RSN_CD

Comment: Are you familiar with joins, primary keys, and foreign keys?

Comment: No, I am not very familiar with much database stuff. All my knowledge is just lookup -- sel * from, etc. This query has been provided to me already.

Comment: I think you would be best served by reading up on joins and keys, then. This is what puts the "R" in "RDBMS". Looks like this is a real web site and it explains it fairly efficiently: http://www.sql-join.com/

Comment: JOIN both of your SELECT queries. You should come up with something like this for a start `SELECT...FROM...JOIN...ON...WHERE...UNION... SELECT...FROM...JOIN...ON...WHERE` http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide us with the full field list of `EQ.TE_LOCO_EQP` to answer this question in full, yet I think you'll be able to manage with what I have provided you below. Replace what is in the square brackets ([]) with the field relevant for the join.

I agree with @Snowman in that you could easily research this one.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        TRNSP_EQP_EIN
        ,TRNSP_EQP_ID
        ,PRE_EQP_ID
        ,EQP_GRP
        ,AAR_CT_C
        ,AAR_MCHDSG_C
        ,BLD_D
        ,REBLD_D
    FROM
        EQ.TE_TRNSP_EQPACTV  A
    WHERE 
        TRNSP_EQP_ID = ‘BNSF0000000123’
    UNION
    SELECT
        TRNSP_EQP_EIN
        ,TRNSP_EQP_ID
        ,PRE_EQP_ID
        ,EQP_GRP
        ,AAR_CT_C
        ,AAR_MCHDSG_C
        ,BLD_D
        ,REBLD_D
    FROM 
        EQ.TE_TRNSP_EQPHIST  B
    WHERE
        A.TRNSP_EQP_ID = ‘ABC0123’

    ORDER BY
        TRNSP_EQP_EFF_TS
    WITH UR /* No idea what this is? */
) X
LEFT JOIN
    EQ.TE_LOCO_EQP Y
ON 
    X.[PRIMARY_KEY] = Y.[EQUIVELANT_FOREIGN_KEY]
```

Comment: `ORDER BY` in Derived Tables is not allowed in Teradata, so move it after the join. And it's probably safe to use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` should be much more efficient and the optimizer might do a better plan.